# How do I activate my Collector's Edition digital items?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm supposed to have a pet and other goods in my inventory, but I don't see it there. Was I supposed to use another activation code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click the new mail icon in the bottom left.
2. Click the icon to accept the items into your inventory.
3. Right-click the items in your inventory to activate.
4. Toggle the pet via the mirror icon on the bottom right.

Took me a while to figure this out.